# Python/Django: how to assert that unit test result contains a certain string?

Tags: python, json, django, unit-testing, assert

In a python unit test (actually Django), what is the correct `assert` statement that will tell me if my test result contains a string of my choosing?

```
self.assertContainsTheString(result, {"car" : ["toyota","honda"]})
```

I want to make sure that my `result` contains at least the json object (or string) that I specified as the second argument above

```
{"car" : ["toyota","honda"]}
```

Comment: would [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.json] help?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
self.assertContains(result, "abcd")
```

You can modify it to work with json.

Use `self.assertContains` only for `HttpResponse` objects. For other objects, use `self.assertIn`.

Comment: yes but due to the json structure, it could have some whitespace added which are not problematic in json but problematic if you want to compare with a python string.

Comment: assertContains is not intended to by used for other object than HttpReponse, prefer using assertTrue with "in" python keyword instead (see my answser below).

Comment: This is wrong. Assertconains is for http responses.

Comment: This answer should clarify that it is tailored for HttpResponse only

Answer (score 162):

To assert if a string is or is not a substring of another, you should use `assertIn` and `assertNotIn`:

```py
# Passes
self.assertIn('bcd', 'abcde')

# AssertionError: 'bcd' unexpectedly found in 'abcde'
self.assertNotIn('bcd', 'abcde')
```

These are new since [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn) and [Python 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn)

Comment: Also `assertIn` provides helpful messages on failure as you've illustrated.

Answer (score 31):

You can write assertion about expected part of string in another string with a simple assertTrue + in python keyword :

```
self.assertTrue("expected_part_of_string" in my_longer_string)
```

Comment: The issue with this strategy is that is can give poor failure messages of the form "AssertionError: False is not true"

Comment: @jamesc agree with you, test should show the error details,   any workaround to this issue if using assertTrue?

Comment: @LukAron If you have to use assertTrue, then you could pass a message which you build beforehand to contain more details: assertTrue(expr, msg=message). If the message gets complicated, then you can extract the message building and assertTrue check into a separate assertion helper, which may have its own tests to ensure it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 11):

Build a JSON object using `json.dumps()`.

Then compare them using `assertEqual(result, your_json_dict)`

```
import json

expected_dict = {"car":["toyota", "honda"]}
expected_dict_json = json.dumps(expected_dict)

self.assertEqual(result, expected_dict_json)
```

Comment: Why using `assertTrue()` instead of [`assertEqual()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual)? At least with `assertEqual()`, the module will print both the result and the expected values.

Comment: You are right, assertEqual() is better. I can't find the link but I was pretty sure to have read somewhere to use assertTrue instead of assertEqual. Obviously, I was wrong :) I'll fix the example above.

Comment: Note that this will be unreliable when you have more than one key in any dictionary because the `dumps()` uses arbitrary ordering and we don't know the ordering of keys in `result`.  You'd be much better off using `self.assertEqual(json.loads(result), expected_dict)`.

Answer (score 10):

[As mentioned by Ed I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021102/1286705), `assertIn` is probably the simplest answer to finding one string in another. However, the question states:

> I want to make sure that my `result` contains at least the json object (or string) that I specified as the second argument above,i.e., `{"car" : ["toyota","honda"]}`

Therefore I would use multiple assertions so that helpful messages are received on failure - tests will have to be understood and maintained in the future, potentially by someone that didn't write them originally. Therefore assuming we're inside a `django.test.TestCase`:

```
# Check that `car` is a key in `result`
self.assertIn('car', result)
# Compare the `car` to what's expected (assuming that order matters)
self.assertEqual(result['car'], ['toyota', 'honda'])
```

Which gives helpful messages as follows:

```
# If 'car' isn't in the result:
AssertionError: 'car' not found in {'context': ..., 'etc':... }
# If 'car' entry doesn't match:
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['toyota', 'honda'] != ['honda', 'volvo']

First differing element 0:
toyota
honda

- ['toyota', 'honda']
+ ['honda', 'volvo']
```